# Can I input Git command in Android Studio IDE?

Tags: android-studio, github

I use Github in Android Studio 3.3.1. I know I can open Version Control using Alt+9.

And Git command and result will be displayed in Console of Version Control. Can I input Git command and run it directly in Android Studio IDE ?

Answer (score 26):

**Yes sure.**
About android studio on Windows you can change default command line to "bash"
First install [git bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads)
then Setting in android studio to run terminal from bash

1. File -> Settings search for "terminal"
2. In topic "terminal" select on "Application settings" title then change "Shell path" to the directory of installed  "git bash" 
   *default root shell is "C/Program file/git/bin/bash"*

close your current terminal and open new one in android so you will see new terminal with can use git command.

Comment: you need to select executable path not directory... `E:\programs\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe`

Answer (score 14):

From your Android studio ->

Go to -

**File->Settings->Tools->Terminal**
Make your settings there.

[image: Android studio terminal]

Hope you will be able to find out the **Terminal**.

[image: Android studio with terminal]

Answer (score 5):

or, for windows 10 on the File->Setting->Terminal->Shell path change the cmd.exe to powershell.exe. You will get git and also more linux commands plus some cool colors etc.