# Error on add project to github from android studio

Tags: android, github

I have android project hosted on github after making some changes in code when I am trying to add code to github from android studio it is showing something like this:

[image]

Someone please let me know why this error is showing.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [open a terminal within your Android Studio session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55016133/6309), and see if one of the solutions of "[How to resolve “`Error: bad index – Fatal: index file corrupt`” when using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1115956/6309)" applies.

Typically, try first to remove the `index` file in the `.git/` subfolder of your local Git repository.
Followed by a `git reset`.

Comment: Thanks bro its working fine,but why this error happen

Comment: @Digvijay Does it happens regularly? Because some IDE can have background processes checking for remote new commits, which could interfere with the index.

Comment: No it happened for the first time only before that data was adding easily to github.

Comment: @Digvijay OK. Let me know if the error pops up again.